# Do I need to add every test user to users list for unverified app in google developer console?

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I have created a google account to access People API Contacts using Nodejs app.
My app is in testing phase (so user limit is 100).
I am able to access contacts of two other google accounts using my app but not more than that `Gives error 403`.

So after two users do I need to add every new user to the users list in the developer console, so as to allow my app to access that user's Contacts using `People API`?

Comment: Can you share more information on what are you doing and how are you doing it?

Comment: I have created 3 google accounts say A, B and C. Using account A I have created client credentials at google console for Web App client. In all three account I have added contacts. Use case is I will execute the Nodejs example provided by google to access People API using client credentials created using.  I am able to access the contacts of account A and B separately but when I select account C during user authorization it gives 403 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after some trial and error. Test user has to be added when the app is still in testing phase. Once we submit the app for google verification we don't need to add the test user to the users list. Earlier I had submitted for google verification and was testing, so during that time I was able to access contacts of any gmail account. Later I moved the app back to testing so it was not able to access contacts from new gmail account.
Hence we need to add test user to users list until the app is submitted for google verification.